# How to post a file to a variable (with type 'HttpPostedFileBase' ) in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, file-upload, httppostedfilebase

I have a variable with `HttpPostedFileBase` as **type** in my model. The model is given below:

```
    public class MailModel
    {
        public int mail_id { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string To { get; set; }
        public string subject { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }

    }
```

Now I want to assign a value to the variable `file`  from my **local** **file path**. How can I assign a value to `file` in the corresponding controller?

```
    public class MailController : Controller
    {
       MailModel mm = new MailModel();
       mm.file = ?            //Can I add a filepath?
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: I am a bit confused "I want to assign a value to the variable file from my local file path", what does this mean exactly?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do? `HttpPostedFileBase` is used to bind to a file input in your view, and that can only be set by the user selecting a file in the browser.

Comment: I want to update variable 'file' in my controller, I want to assign a pdf file to it from my local path

Comment: What exactly are you doing with `file` property of the model class? `HttpPostedFileBase` commonly used for getting the file from client to server so that is assigned internally. Why you want to assign it explicitly?

Comment: `I want to update variable 'file' in my controller` why? If you can explain the use case, better suggestions and approaches can be provided.

Comment: By update, you mean you want to bound the posted file to that object parameter?

Comment: `HttpPostedFileBase` is an abstract class. You need to assign an object of HttpPostedFile class to it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have updated my question. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: You cannot set the value of a file input for security reasons - the only way it can be set is by the user selecting a file in the browser (what is it that you are trying to do?)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, Thank you. But how can I store a file without 'HttpPostedFileBase'?

Comment: What do you mean _store a file_? Its not clear what you are wanting to do. You view should include `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.file, new { type = "file" })` and when you submit you form, the value of `file` will be populated (and you can then save it)

Comment: I want to generate pdf file dynamically. After the creation of pdf file I want to assign it to variable 'file'.

Comment: You cannot. But what makes you think you want to assign it to a `HttpPostedFileBase` property?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke , Which is the type that I want to store the variable 'file'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168523/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-vignesh-vs).

Comment: I got the solution for this. I have added it below. Thank you all for your support :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution. I have converted the file path into bytes using the following code:

```
    byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
```

I created a  derived class for `HttpPostedFileBase`  in `MailModel`.

```
    public class MemoryPostedFile : HttpPostedFileBase
    {
        private readonly byte[] FileBytes;
        private string FilePath;

        public MemoryPostedFile(byte[] fileBytes, string path, string fileName = null)
        {
            this.FilePath = path;
            this.FileBytes = fileBytes;
            this._FileName = fileName;
            this._Stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
        }

        public override int ContentLength { get { return FileBytes.Length; } }
        public override String FileName { get { return _FileName; } }
        private String _FileName;
        public override Stream InputStream
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Stream == null)
                {
                    _Stream = new FileStream(_FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                }
                return _Stream;
            }
        }
        private Stream _Stream;
        public override void SaveAs(string filename)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath)); 
        }
    }
```

Then I call it from MailController using the following code:

```
public class MailController: Controller
{
   byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
   MailModel model= new MailModel();
   model.file = (HttpPostedFileBase)new MemoryPostedFile(bytes, FilePath, filename);
}
```

Now I can assign a value to the variable "file" (with type **HttpPostedFileBase**)